# Laravel 5 Form request and user register

Tags: forms, laravel-5

The problem is, you need to simultaneously register the user and to enter into another table with its data forms and assign the ID

i tried

```
$data = Request::all();

    $user = new App\User();
    $user->username = $data['name'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $user->save();
```

how to immediately get a new user ID?

that would record other data such as

```
$question = new App\Question();
$question->name_q = $data['name_q'];
$question->body_q = $data['body_q'];
$question->user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have relationship defined for that so that you can easily insert data without creating objects of two different tables. Lets first look at your case and then I will show you how to do it a better way.

```
$data = Request::all();

$user = new App\User();
$user->username = $data['name'];
$user->email = $data['email'];
$user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
$user->save();

$question = new App\Question();
$question->name_q = $data['name_q'];
$question->body_q = $data['body_q'];
$question->user_id = $user->id;
$question->save();
```

and we are done. But in this case you have to create objects of two different tables and write everything that is ok as of now but what happens when you have to insert data into many many tables at a go. Lets see that:

Define a relationship first which you already have, lets see what we should have in the model :

```
//User model should have a questions function
public function questions()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
  }

//Question model should have a user model
public function user()
 {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
```

and now what we will do is

```
$user = new App\User();
$user->username = $data['name'];
$user->email = $data['email'];
$user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
$user->save();


$user->questions()->create([
            'field' => $somevariable,
             'field' => $someothervariable
        ]);
//here questions is the function name in User model
```